# Update one property value of one object in array of objects, return updated array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

I am trying to update one value `is_deleted` in an array of objects for the deleted object.

```js
  const handleDelete = (idx) => {
    const filteredCards = cards.map((card, i) => {
      if(i == idx) {
        card.is_deleted = true;
        return {...cards}
      }
    })
   setCards(filteredCards);
  }
```

**Output**

```
cards = [
  undefined,
  [
   { id: 1, is_deleted: false },
   { id: 2, is_deleted: true },
  ]
]
```

**Desired Output**

```
cards = [
 { id: 1, is_deleted: false },
 { id: 2, is_deleted: true },
]
```

The output is partially right - at index 1 I see the two cards, with the second `is_deleted` being set to `true`. However, at index 0 there is an "undefined".

Any insight into why this is would be helpful! Thank you and let me know if I missed a key piece of info.

Comment: Can you show your cards array before the function?

Comment: The output has incorrect syntax

Answer (score 1):

You could just access the card directly, rather than using `map`:

```js
let cards = [
  { id: 1, is_deleted: false },
  { id: 2, is_deleted: false },
]
const setCards = c => cards = c(cards.slice())

const handleDelete = idx => setCards(cards => (cards[idx].is_deleted = true, cards))

handleDelete(1)
console.log(cards)
```

The `setCards` function is just mimicking react's `useState`.

Comment: you are still mutating the state `cards[idx].is_deleted = true`

Comment: @ajaiJothi Yeah, but that's why react lets you provide a function to access the old state first.

Comment: yes, but you are still updating the value of a reference. `cards before update` and `cards after update` are equal in your code since it shares the same reference

Comment: partially. `cards[idx].is_deleted = true` -> still mutating the state. `cards[idx] before and after update` are same

Comment: But that's the intended way? @ajaiJothi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204138/discussion-between-ajai-jothi-and-kobe).